# Create a native javafx app with Inno Setup and maven

Tags: maven, javafx, native, inno-setup

I've a little JavaFX app and I use Maven for managing the dependencies thanks to the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin).

This plugin have an option who will build a native installer based on the settings (mvn jfx:build-native) using InnoSetup (on windows)

That's work pretty well but I can't find where I can specify all the Inno Setup options (like those visible [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setupiconfile)). Did I have to add something on my pom ? Did I have to create a .iss file ? If yes, how to specify the link to this file ?

Any idea ?

Comment: A number of options is available through plugin configuration (like, icon or offline mode), see https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/wiki , Usage section.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice way to start... but a lot of option are missing =/

We can read "The 'nativeInstaller' element can also be customised" but there is no doc about this (here : https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/wiki/Building-native-bundles )

Comment: True, and  https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zenjava/javafx/maven/plugin/NativeMojo.java doesn't seem to have what you need. Nice opportunity for you to contribute, huh? :)

Comment: Yes indeed, but right now, I've no idea of what I've to do for contributing =/

Answer (score 5):

> Where to put "Inno Setup" file (*.iss)?

When using javafx-maven-plugin you can add inno setup file into:

```
src/main/deploy/package/windows/project-name.iss
```

**Referencing files in iss**

If you need to reference some files in setup file your root will be on:

```
target/jfx/native/bundles
```

So for example to pack whole project use:

```
...
[Files]
Source: "project-name\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
...
```

That will pack all files from:

```
target/jfx/native/bundles/project-name/*
```

**Adding application icon**

For simple icon you can just put it in:

```
src/main/deploy/package/windows/project-name.ico
```

And in iss put this:

```
...
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
...
```

And don`t forget to define: MyAppExeName and MyAppName.

Comment: Hi @pawel-kapalla How to add license file in inno script. My inno script code like `LicenseFile=license.txt` and I added license.txt file in `\src\main\deploy\package\windows`. In Inno script studio, I can run it but I'm getting the error while build using maven. It means inno script not able to find that file. Thanks

Comment: fast anwser try LicenseFile={app}\license.txt i will check it exactly when i get back to home

Comment: Thanks :) But I already tried that one. it's not working. Actually {app} is for directory where application will install. you can check it here http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm

Comment: i didnt do it for quite some time but you can try something like that: `SourceDir=c:\license_dir LicenseFile="license.txt"` i know it not best solution but i worked for me. The and base path that inno is using seems to lead to Inno Setup installation directory it doesnt see anything in src path probably you would have to move some license files to assembly directory where inno is started but i dont remember how. In inno install directory you can find some examples in subfolder  Examples maybe they will be of any help.

Comment: I am attempting to add an INNO setup file to my project, but when maven runs it is not using it.  I have it located in the src/main/deploy/package/windows/appname.iss  Not sure if there is something else I need to set?

Comment: check if you have configured javafx-maven-plugin example: https://github.com/Xesenix/javafx-experiment01/blob/master/pom.xml and you need to run build with "mvn jfx:build-native" setting

Comment: @PawełKapalla do not run "jfx:build-native" it is only ment for normal maven-lifecycle via ```mvn package```, just calling "jfx:native" with latest version (8.1.3 currently) should be enough.